# Oracle APEX chart - Invalid data is displayed

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a gauge chart that displays a value label and a percentage. it is based on a query that returns VALUE and MAX_VALUE. In some cases the query returns 0 as MAX_VALUE and then the chart displays a message 'Invalid data'. I believe this is happening because of division by zero.  How to prevent this message from getting displayed and return 0 as both VALUE and MAX_VALUE and 0%?

```
SELECT NUM_FAILED VALUE, TOTAL_NUM MAX_VALUE
 FROM
(
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select t1.name, t1.run_id
    from Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
    WHERE t1.START_DATE > SYSDATE - 1
    GROUP BY t1.name, t1.run_id)
) AS TOTAL_NUM,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select name, run_id
    from Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Tabe2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
    where t1.run_id IN (SELECT run_id FROM Table1 where err_code > 0)
    AND  t1.START_DATE > SYSDATE - 1
    GROUP BY  t1.name,  t1.run_id)
) as NUM_FAILED
FROM dual)
```

Comment: Could you post a query (chart source)?

Comment: I added the query

Comment: the problem happens when both parts of the query return 0

Comment: Hello, I suggest that when you post some questions related to charts in apex, you use the tag "oracle-jet". Maybe you'll find someone there who knows how to customize these charts on apex. In that case, I would solve this problem using decode. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting a query.

If you want to avoid 0 as a result, how about `DECODE`?

```
SELECT decode(NUM_FAILED, 0, 1E99, NUM_FAILED) VALUE,
       decode(TOTAL_NUM , 0, 1E99, TOTAL_NUM ) MAX_VALUE
FROM (the rest of your query goes here)
```

You didn't say what's going on afterwards (i.e. what exactly causes division by zero - is it `NUM_FAILED`, or `TOTAL_NUM`)? The idea is: instead of dividing by zero, divide by a very large value (such as 1E99) and you'll get a very small number, for example:

```
SQL> select 24/1E99 from dual;

   24/1E99
----------
2,4000E-98

SQL>
```

which is, practically, *zero*. See if you can do something with such an approach.

Comment: I tried decode before, replacing 0 with 1 but it is not a very elegant solution:( TOTAL_NUm is the one causing a problem since it is division by 0

Comment: I was hoping there was a better solution, something built in in APEX

Comment: Maybe there is, but I don't know it. Someone else might, though.

Comment: thank you for trying to help. I am at my wits end trying to figure it out:(